# C# Iterate over user settings and change value dynamically

Tags: c#, properties, settings

I want to dynamically change the value of the `Property.settings` with user scope. If I debug the values with `console.printline` everything seems good. But the value doesn't change.

I have a data grid where I can change the setting values. So if you write something in the row then the value should change.

```
IEnumerator enumerator =  Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues.GetEnumerator();

Console.WriteLine("Itemname:: " + enumerator.ToString());

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    SettingsPropertyValue item = (SettingsPropertyValue)enumerator.Current;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg_values.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].ToString().Equals(item.Name) && row.Cells[2].Value != null)
        {
            item.PropertyValue = row.Cells[2].Value;
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: may you have to save it ? :-)
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

Comment: row.Cells[0].Values was missing ;// my bad. Everything works now.

Comment: Yes the Code works like it should. There was just the .Values missing. Where can i mark the Question as answerd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to save after changing the value. You will find something like this item.Save() or near to this syntax.